# Need help: Sorting elements of a combo box in ArcGIS Java script API (ver. 2.8)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, combo-box

I am using sorting elements in combo box in ArcGIS Java Script API (v.2.8) & for sorting I am using “ fetchProperties="{sort:[{attribute:'name', descending:false}]}".
All entries in combo box are sorting excluding “ALL” entry.

So I am not able to understand that why “ALL” is not sorting ascending. It is displaying at the end but when make “descending: true” then its displaying first.

I want to put “ALL” in the beginning of the combo-box. Therefore, any help will be great.

Please check the screenshot below: enter image description here[image: As you can see all elements are sorting but the "ALL" entry is not sorting]

Image :

Code is :

```
  //combo box item
  function populateList(results) {
    //Populate the dropdown list box with unique values
    //alert("sss:  "+results.length);
    var zone;
    var values = [];
    var testVals={};

    //Add option to display all zoning types to the dropdown list 
    //values.push({name:"ALL"})

    var features = results.features;
    //values.push({name:'ALL'});
    dojo.forEach (features, function(feature) {
      zone = feature.attributes.TOPIC;

      if (!testVals[zone]) {
        testVals[zone] = true;
        values.push({name:zone});

      }
    });

    var dataItems = {
           identifier: 'name',
           label: 'name',
           items: values
    };
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data:dataItems});
    dijit.byId("mySelect").store = store;
    values.push({name:"ALL"})
  }
```

Comment: Let me know if you require the complete code..

Comment: I am referring this (http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/08/30/populate-a-combo-box-with-unique-values-using-a-query-layer/) link & the example mentioned in the link

Comment: please post the code

Comment: @David combo-box elements are coming from 'topic' column and  I have added "ALL" element to display all the records..thanks for your response

Comment: How should I enter code to proper format here (without any gap) ??..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code I assume you tried pushing in the 'All' Item to the array before the result items? This should work, the order of the array controls the order they appear. Just tidied up the code and added both a label and an identifier (I don't think this is required to be different or controls the order).

Update:
[Here is a JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dave_wilton/a6rar/) running in 2.8 returning the results in the correct order

```
            var dataItems = {
                identifier: 'id',
                label: 'name',
                items: values
            };

            dataItems.items.push({ name: 'ALL', id: 0 });

            var features = results.features;
            var i = 1;
            var zone;
            dojo.forEach(features, function(feature) {
                zone = feature.attributes.TOPIC;
                if (zone) {
                    if (!testVals[zone]) {
                        testVals[zone] = true;
                         dataItems.items.push({ name: zone, id: i });
                    ++i;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt  response !! Let me try then I will get back to you..

Comment: I added a JS fiddle to show code running

Comment: @David..thanks I am testing this @ my end..thanks a lot : )

Comment: @David.. I tried your way and its working : ) so thanks a lot David once again..You are great !!