# Upgrading custom Java script tool (ver. 1.3 to 3.1 ) for ArcGIS Java Script API and getting error?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have found useful tool [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/05/29/an-easier-way-to-zoom-a-dojo-dijit-that-zooms-to-states-and-counties/) (All US States and counties on combo-box) its using Java script API 1.3 version.

I have downloaded the tool and trying use but its gives an store error (using version 3.1) but when I change the version to 2.8 its working fine..so how do I implement it for 3.1 version.

Is there any document or instructions ?? (Because Esri mentions that only upgrade the version no. ex.  2.8 to 3.1 )..

Software that I am using is ArcGIS Java Script API ver 3.0 & ArcGIS Server 10.1,Desktop 10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At ESRI 3.0 the dojo version behind the ESRI framework was upgraded to 1.7. Dojo 1.7 has a fundamental change to the way in which modules are loaded called AMD. See [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/migration_30.htm) help topic for advice on migrating to AMD and the 3.0 [release notes](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/06/13/arcgis-api-for-javascript-version-3-0-released-2/). You look should at these topics in order to understand what changed between the two versions

When I created a fiddle for your [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42294/need-help-sorting-elements-of-a-combo-box-in-arcgis-java-script-api-ver-2-8/42343#42343) I initially created it using version 3, but as you specifically requested the code in 2.8 I changed it. Here is the one I created using ESRI version 3.2 (and therefore dojo version 1.7), notice the differences in how the modules are required (no more dojo.require). Whilst there is some backwards compatibility, it is highly recommeneded you move to the new model as at dojo 2.0 backwards compatibility will not be supported (i.e anywhere you use dojo.)

http://jsfiddle.net/dave_wilton/WrkwX/

Comment: @David..thanks for your detail information ..I followed your links & its almost resolved..I like you explanation (very easy and to the point)...thanks a lot : )

Answer (score 1):

In the tool you've downloaded, try replacing any uses of dojo.store.Memory with dijit.form.ItemFileReadStore to store the state and county data. Data on ItemFileReadStore can be found [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html).